# Woocommerce custom attributes as a values for price range

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to modify existing woocommerce price slider for sorting on custom attribute value not by price, but stuck at modding sql query.

Here is a part of standard woocommerce price query to sql, but modified for getting one custom attribute ranges:

```
    $sql  = "SELECT min( FLOOR( post_meta.meta_value ) ) as min_maxcarry, max( CEILING( post_meta.meta_value ) ) as max_maxcarry FROM {$wpdb->posts} ";
    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} as post_meta ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = post_meta.post_id " . $meta_query_sql['join'];
    $sql .= "   WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type IN ('" . implode( "','", array_map( 'esc_sql', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_post_type', array( 'product' ) ) ) ) . "')
                AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish'
                AND post_meta.meta_key IN ('" . implode( "','", array_map( 'esc_sql', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_post_type', array( '_maxcarry' ) ) ) ) . "')
                AND post_meta.meta_value > '' ";
    $sql .= $meta_query_sql['where'];
    var_dump( $sql );
    return $wpdb->get_row( $sql );
```

Anyone can help with it or suggest another way to show this slider? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
    $meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query );
    $tax_query  = new WP_Tax_Query( $tax_query );
    $meta_query_sql = $meta_query->get_sql( 'post', $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );
    $tax_query_sql  = $tax_query->get_sql( $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );

    $sql  = "SELECT min( FLOOR( post_meta.meta_value ) ) as min_attr, max( CEILING( post_meta.meta_value ) ) as max_attr FROM {$wpdb->posts} ";
    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} as post_meta ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = post_meta.post_id " . $tax_query_sql['join'] . $meta_query_sql['join'];
    $sql .= "   WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type IN ('" . implode( "','", array_map( 'esc_sql', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_post_type', array( 'product' ) ) ) ) . "')
                AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish'
                AND post_meta.meta_key IN ('" . implode( "','", array_map( 'esc_sql', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_filter_meta_keys', array( '_prod_sort_wcpaaf_sort' ) ) ) ) . "')
                AND post_meta.meta_value > '' ";
    $sql .= $tax_query_sql['where'] . $meta_query_sql['where'];
    return $wpdb->get_row( $sql );
```

Will leave it here for anyone, who find it useful. Sidenote for this - don't forget about taxonomy query and change string in code above **_prod_sort_wcpaaf_sort** for another meta key, which you use in project.

Comment: Where in this do you add the attribute you are targeting?